# Pentaho BI Server - JPivot View

Tags: windows-ce, pentaho

Is it possbile to desactivate/disable the plugin  JPivot View in Pentaho .

PS: the version of Pentaho : BI server CE 5.0.1

Thanks

Comment: As far as I remember, I think you should delete jPivot folder form bi-server\pentaho-solutions\system path.

Comment: If you don't want to delete the folder (perhaps you want to enable it later on), just rename the plugin.xml file to anything else (e.g., plugin.xml.disabled). If a plugin folder does not have a plugin.xml file it won't be loaded.